# Flutter desktop paste text in textfield Ctrl + V (Windows)

Tags: flutter, textfield, paste, flutter-desktop

When i try to paste text inside a `Textfield` in my Windows `Flutter Desktop` project an unsupported symbol is shown:

[image]

I found [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42535) on github about MacOS but i wasn't able to find a similar issue about Windows.

Is there any workaround i can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary workaround you could add your own key handler for that text field and implement paste using [Clipboard](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/Clipboard-class.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it and `Clipboard` is returning data. Now i opened [a new issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60682045/rawkeyevent-wrong-characters-in-windows10-flutter-desktop) because using `RawKeyboardListener` I'm getting wrong characters, so i could not use CTRL + V as event to read from `Clipboard` (i could use a button but that would be nasty)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize key events had regressed on Windows when suggesting using your own handler.