# RawKeyEvent wrong characters in Windows10 [Flutter desktop]

Tags: flutter, keyboard-events, flutter-desktop

I'm testing `RawKeyboardListener` in a `Flutter Desktop` project (Windows 10).

Events work fine, but i receive wrong keys label, as you can see below:

[image]

Is it a "keyboard layout" issue, like if the app was expecting events from an android keyboard with different key positions (As you can see in the .gif i receive and "Unknown Android key code")?
How can i fix that?

Also, if i print `event.isControlPressed` it always return `false` even if i'm pressing it.

This is the code i'm using:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  // See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells#target-platform-override
  if (!kIsWeb && (Platform.isLinux || Platform.isWindows)) {
    debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.fuchsia;
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: RawKeyboardListener(
          child: TextField(),
          focusNode: FocusNode(),
          onKey: (event) async {
            if (event.runtimeType == RawKeyDownEvent) {
              print(
                  'id: ${event.logicalKey.keyId}, label: ${event.logicalKey.keyLabel} debugName: ${event.logicalKey.debugName}');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's [a bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37710). There's nothing you can do at the level of your application to fix it.

Until it's fixed, the only thing you could do would be to write your key handling entirely in terms of key codes, rather than logical keys.